# How to Add Custom Rule to FXCop for avoiding == operator inside the method

Tags: c#, fxcop

I want to add a Custom rule for avoiding the '==' operator inside a method in a class.
For example in the below method i need to avoid *'str1==str2'* with *string.Compare(str1, str2,StringComparison.Ordinal);*.So I need to check this types of code are appear in any of the method

```
public void StringTest2()
    {
        string str1 = "Hello";
        string str2 = "HELLO";
        if (str1 == str2)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Out of interest, *why* would you want to avoid this, insisting on a far more verbose version which achieves the same result?

Comment: But I need to avoid the == operator. How to check this type of code is present inside the method?

Comment: "I need to" is in no way an answer to my question of *why* you think you need to.

Comment: I think string.compare is the best method for comparing a string than == .

Comment: is there is any globalization problem using '==' operator in the code for comparing a string?

Comment: No. The `==` operator performs an ordinal comparison. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just say no.

The [string == operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.op_equality.aspx) already performs an ordinal comparison, and is considerably more readable IMO than insisting on using `string.Compare`.

Even if you *did* want an ordinal string comparison explicitly, I'd suggest using [`string.Equals(string, string, StringComparison)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks.aspx) instead of `Compare`.

Comment: Your answer is a solution.But How to add a custom rule for checking 'string == operator' in the method?

Comment: @Jameel: I suspect it may not even be possible, but I don't know much about FxCop. I know enough to know I would violently protest against such a rule being enforced on me though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
**The below code checks both the assignment and equal to operator in an assembly**


public override ProblemCollection Check(Member member)
            {
                var method = member as Method;
                if (method == null)
                    return null;
                if (method.Instructions.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var instruction in method.Instructions)
                    {
                        if (instruction != null)
                            if ( instruction.OpCode == OpCode.Ceq)
                            {
                                var resolution = GetResolution(member.Name.Name);
                                var problem = new Problem(resolution, member)
                                                  {
                                                      Certainty = 95,
                                                      FixCategory = FixCategories.Breaking,
                                                      MessageLevel = MessageLevel.Warning
                                                  };
                                Problems.Add(problem);
                            }
                    }
                }
                return base.Problems;
            }
```